# API on google cloud is giving 401 error randomly even when the token seems fine

Tags: javascript, python, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am using  Firebase Javascript SDK version 9.8.1 in front-end to generate user tokens from firebase. Here is how the code looks like:

```js
const getAuthIDToken = async () => {
    try {
        const authToken = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken();
        return authToken;
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during token retrieval
        console.error("Error getting authentication ID token:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

On the backend side, I am using Python firebase-admin==6.2.0 to verify the id tokens, the code looks like:

```py
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, auth
import jwt
  
def check_token_jwt(request):
    bearer_token = ""
    if "authorization" in request.headers:
        bearer_token = request.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1]
    if "Authorization" in request.headers:
        bearer_token = request.headers["Authorization"].split(" ")[1]
    if bearer_token == "":
        return False, None
    try:
        val = auth.verify_id_token(bearer_token)
        if (
            "user_id" in val
            and "iss" in val
            and val["iss"] == "******"
            and val["aud"] == "******"
        ):
            try:
                user = auth.get_user(val["user_id"])
                return True, user
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return False, None
        else:
            return False, None
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print(e)
        val = jwt.decode(bearer_token, options={"verify_signature": False})
        if (
            "aud" in val
            and "email" in val
            and val["email"] == "****"
            and val["aud"] == "****"
        ):
            return True, "serviceaccount"
        else:
            return False, None
```

And at times, I get error like:

[image: GCloud Function Logs]

The error is not persistent, I face it randomly at times, and for the same code it will work fine most of the time. I have the same code in all of my APIs, but I have faced issue with only 3 of them. I tried to use jwt.io to understand the bearer token for which it failed, but I couldn't find any issue, it was identical with bearer Token that worked. The same token is failing for the 3 APIs while at the same time working for other APIs even though they essentially have same code for generation and verification.